# I cannot detect an environment variable from my unit test

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

My web app depends on an environment variable.
I wrote a unit test to ensure the environment variable is not null. The test passes on my local machine because, of course, I put the environment variable in my system variables. I had to restart Visual Studio for it to recognize the environment variable.  But the test fails when it is built using CI in the cloud. 
The TFS Build is scheduled to deploy it to a staging environment, and the environment variable is present in the staging environment as well as the production environment. If it is successful, it will deploy it to the staging environment, and then auto-swap with production. But it doesn't get far because the unit test fails. Is the unit test run in an environment different from the actual hosted website? If so, I must change my unit test strategy to not test environment variables. I may make an application status page to check such things then. But I wondered if anyone knew what was up on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom environment variable which you have in your personal machine must also be on the build controller. TFS Builds run on controller (Agents internally) and the unit tests run post build of the binary (Integral part of the Build before packaging)

Check if you can add the environment variable in the Build controller. You probably would need to reach the Build team and get that environment variable added in the Build server.

You also have a choice to "Pass the build if the unit test fails"

You can also categorize the unit test and set priorities and run only unit tests of certain priority; like priority 1 alone. You ca eliminate the case which is failing to be part of a unit test priority which you want to run.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Now that you say it, it seems so obvious. Unit Tests run on the build controller. That is different from the machine that hosts the application. I think my strategy of testing environment variables in unit tests is inherently flawed. I will stop trying to use unit tests to test platform configuration and integration issues.